# Python pandas replace value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

When I look at the values in a column in my dataframe, I can see that due to user data entry errors, the same category has been entered incorrectly.

For my dataframe I use this code:

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
 Targeted    523534
 targeted    1
 story       25425
 story       2
 multiple    2524543
```

For story, I guess there is a space?

I am trying to replace targeted with Targeted.

```
df['column_name'].replace("targeted","Targeted")
```

But nothing is happening, I still get the same value count.

Comment: Did you `df['column_name'].replace("targeted","Targeted").value_counts()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is seems there is start of end white-space(s).

Need [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) first and then [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip().replace("targeted","Targeted")
```

---

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip().str.replace("targeted","Targeted")
```

Another possible solution is convert all characters to lowercase:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip().str.lower()
```

Comment: thank you , this option worked the best df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip().replace("targeted","Targeted")